# Construct - make a function call to web page and give a callback function to be called later

Tags: construct-2, construct-3

Is it possible in Construct2/3 to make a function call to web page and give a callback function name to web page so its called later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax: c2_callFunction("get_score")